# ActiveRecord Association Type Mismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

A bit more context. I'm using devise to create members. Upon signup i'd like a user to select an item from a database of itmes and have that item assoiciated with that member. so i can call `item.members.new` in the consol without the following assiciation error:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Carrier(#97584750) expected, got String(#83658370)
```

devise registrions/new view
http://pastebin.com/KGnJQp2N

Members model
http://pastebin.com/VmDbpSpY

carriers model
http://pastebin.com/DPEV1NMd

carriers controller
http://pastebin.com/uFfh9KrP

I'm convinced the error is in the following lines:

```
<div><%= f.label :carrier %><br />
<%= f.select :carrier, 
              options_for_select([["Select One", ""], *Carrier.all.map(&:name)]),
              :class => 'genForm_dropBox' %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a stab and say you're doing this in your controller:

```
member.carrier = params[:carrier]
```

But `params[:carrier]` is a string, which contains the `carrier.name`. What you'd do is first assign an id along with your options in the select:

`options_for_select([["Select One", ""], *Carrier.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id] })`

In your controller you would check if carrier is set, and if so, find it based on the id and assign to the association:

`member.carrier = Carrier.find(params[:carrier]) unless params[:carrier].blank?`

or..

```
if params[:carrier].present?
  member.carrier = Carrier.find(params[:carrier])
end
```

Comment: after making the changes it worked peep my code here http://pastebin.com/jupy703e

Comment: Great! But where are assigning carrier to member? I just see `carrier =` with no assignment after that. One reason you might want to avoid `find(name: params[:carrier])` is in case the name is changed after a form is rendered. The `Carrier.id` is a much more reliable attribute.